# Oracle XMLCONCAT assign result to variable

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

Why I can't assign results of XMLCONCAT to varible using below syntax

:= XMLCONCAT (, );

I have below example and XMLCONCAT works only in SELECT XMLCONCAT (, ) INTO  constructions

```
create or replace function  fn_xmlconcat
 return xmltype
as
  v1 xmltype;
  v2 xmltype;
  v3 xmltype;
begin
   select xmlforest(t1.cid,t1.cname,t1.cbday) into v1 from tbl_xmlforest t1 
where cid = 1 ;
   select xmlforest(t2.cid,t2.cname,t2.cbday) into v2 from tbl_xmlforest2 t2 
where cid = 4;
   v3 := xmlconcat(v1,v2);
  --select xmlconcat(v1,v2) into v3 from dual;
   return v3;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of these functions are part of the "SQL/XML standard", being that they are implemented by the SQL engine inside Oracle.  It is the PL/SQL engine that allows for assignment etc.

Often the distinction is blurred, because in PL/SQL we implement many of the same functions that are present in SQL, but not all of them, eg

x := decode(....)

will not work, but

select decode(...)

will.